# Calling functions from header files as an initializer for const variables

Tags: c++, initialization, header-files

In my C++ code, I recently updated a variable called `bufferSignature` from an `unsigned int` to a `const string` to be more descriptive. I need to initialize this variable on the creation of the `VBufferObject` with the return value from a function called `GenerateAlphanumSignature()` in the `SceneManager` namespace.

The problem I'm having here is that I want the variable (`bufferSignature`) to be `const`, as I won't be updating it at all in its lifetime. But I can't initialize it in a constructor. I've tried calling the function in the header to initialize the variable.

I've never had to do this before, so I didn't expect it to work. It didn't. I'm just looking for any workaround on this.

**VBufferObject.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Dependencies.h"
#include "Helpers.h"

#include "SceneManager.h"

namespace Vega
{
    class VBufferObject
    {
    public:
        const std::string bufferSignature = SceneManager::GenerateAlphanumSignature();

        void ComputeIndexArray();

        std::vector<unsigned int> IBD;
        std::vector<glm::vec3> VBD;
        std::vector<glm::vec2> UVBD;
        std::vector<glm::vec3> NBD;
    };
}
```

The code is completely open source: [here](https://github.com/archiemourad/Vega/tree/preview) (branch: preview) if you need to look through the code yourself.

Comment: "_It didn't._": While you can use a constructor definition as shown in the posted answer, your shown code should work just as well since C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't initialize it in a constructor

Yes, you can, actually.  Use the constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), eg:

```
class VBufferObject
{
public:
    const std::string bufferSignature;

    VBufferObject();
    ...
};
```

```
VBufferObject::VBufferObject()
    : bufferSignature(SceneManager::GenerateAlphanumSignature())
{
}
```